# Joint probability of a number of outcomes of a continuous random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, continuity

This is my first posting here and I will be grateful for any help.

Say, I have a 4-sided uneven dice. To describe it, we can define a discrete random variable X with the following outcomes:

$P(X=1) = 0.889; \\ P(X=2) = 0.1; \\ P(X=3) = 0.01; \\ P(X=4)=0.001$

Consider a series of three dice rolling. Given that $X$ is a discrete random variable we can compute probability for each set of outcomes (assuming that the order of the outcomes does not matter):

$$P('111') = 0.889\times0.889\times0.889 = 0.7026 \\
\vdots \\
\begin{align}
P('123') & = P(x_1=1,x_2=2,x_3=3) + P(x_1=1,x_2=3,x_3=2) + P(x_1=2,x_2=1,x_3=3) + P(x_1=3,x_2=1,x_3=2) + P(x_1=2,x_2=3,x_3=1) + P(x_1=3,x_2=2,x_3=1) \\
& = 6 P(x_1=1,x_2=2,x_3=3) \\
& = 6\times0.889\times0.1\times0.01 = 0.005334
\end{align}
\\ \vdots \\
P('444') = 0.001\times0.001\times0.001 = 10^{-9}
$$

I hope my logic and calculations above are correct.

My question is, what should I do if I work with a continuous random variable?

For example, $Y \sim N(0,1)$ and I get three outcomes of $Y$: $y_1, y_2, y_3$. Using the Cumulative distribution function, CDF, I can compute the following probability of each outcome:

$$P(Y < y_1) = CDF_Y(y_1) \\ P(Y < y_2) = CDF_Y(y_2) \\ P(Y < y_3) = CDF_Y(y_3)$$

But how do I compute the joint probability of all three outcomes together, $P(Y < y_1, Y < y_2, Y < y_3)$? Am I allowed to simply multiply the three CDFs? Again, the order of the outcomes does not matter.

Thanks for your help,

Ivan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key criteria is whether or not the random variables are **mutually independent**.

If they *are so*, then the product rule for mutually independent events applies.   Whether or not the random variables are continuous or discrete, the joint cumulative distribution function of several *mutually independent* random variables is the product of their marginal cumulative distribution functions.

$$\mathsf P(Y_1\leq y_1, Y_2\leq y_2,Y_3\leq y_3) ~=~ \mathsf P(Y_1\leq y_1)~\mathsf P(Y_2\leq y_2~)\mathsf P(Y_3\leq y_3)$$

If these random variables are also each continuous–have probability density functions–then the analogous rule applies:

$$f_{Y_1,Y_2,Y_3}(y_1,y_2,y_3)~=~f_{Y_1}(y_1)~f_{Y_2}(y_2)~f_{Y_3}(y_3)$$

But, as stated, that is all only applicable if we have *mutual independence*.   Elsewise you have to use conditioning.

Comment: Thanks Graham, yes the events y1, y2 and y3 are mutually independent, so the multiplication should be applicable here. However, I am not sure how to take into account that the order of the events does not matter. I see that the multiplication of the f(y1)*f(y2)*f(y3) to the number of permutations (3! = 6) is a wrong idea (I may get the probability > 1). But I can't figure out another way to take this into account. Or may be in the case of continuous variables (and CDFs) the permutations should be ignored?